# Issues with the Chrome Driver with C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to setup Selenium Tests with the Selenium web driver. I have installed the Selenium Libraries on the Visual Studio.

I have this code here:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");
```

[image]

I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 85 (SessionNotCreated)
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
> RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
> RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
> RemoteWebDriver.ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
> ChromeDriver.ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
> ChromeDriver.ctor(ChromeOptions options)
> ChromeDriver.ctor()
> UnitTest1.WebDriverTesting() line 70

I have checked the Libraries that I have installed. It as latest version of Chrome driver 90 and also installed version of Chrome is 90.

Any lead will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you have 2 Chromedriver's installed?  Get rid of the top one. You may need to into your `bin` folder and remove the `.exe` manually as well.

Comment: As @JD2775 said. You only need 1 chrome driver. remove the one that says 85. You might wanna check taskmanage rand kill all chromedriver.exe. Also change this line IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("."); so that it uses the bin chromedriver.exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my test and other's suggestion, you can try the following steps to solve the problem about the chrome driver in c#.

First, please install the nuget-package `Selenium.WebDriver` and `Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver`.(Please remove the first nuget-package in your picture)

Second, we can find the chromedriver.exe in the path `packages\Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.90.0.4430.2400\driver\win32\chromedriver.exe`.

Third, please copy the chromedriver.exe to `Project\bin\debug` folder.

Finally, you can try the following code to open the chrome browser with the url `https://www.google.com/`.

```
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(".");
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");
```

Comment: Well Yeah I removed It. I just updated the latest Chrome driver in path and it worked. But i still find your answer is correct.